# Cannot invoke because "this.redisService" is null

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis

I try to use Redis to set stock value.

```
@SpringBootTest
public class RedisDemoTest{

    @Resource
    private RedisService redisService;

    @Test
    public void stockTest() {
        String value  = redisService.setValue("stock:19",10L).getValue("stock:19");
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

And here is my RedisService code

I tried both @Resource and @Autowired

```
@Service
public class RedisService {

    @Resource
    private JedisPool jedisPool;

    public RedisService setValue(String key, Long value){
        Jedis client = jedisPool.getResource();
        client.set(key,value.toString());
        client.close();
        return this;
    }

    public String getValue(String key) {
        Jedis client = jedisPool.getResource();
        String value = client.get(key);
        client.close();
        return value;
    }
```

it shows 1 usage with setValue method, However I had an java.lang.NullPointerException:Cannot invoke "service.RedisService.setValue(String, java.lang.Long)" because "this.redisService" is null

I hope to print out value 10 which is the set value.

Answer (score 0):

the NullPointerExecption in the test code typically has a problem with improper DI. Make sure that your RedisService is properly injected into the RedisDemoTest class.

For instance, the target of the @Resource is based on the Field and Setter Method, so you would need to make a constructor for the setter method, otherwise, it will come out with an error.

I personally recommend using @Autowired, or @Inject, because @Resource is deprecated since Java 9 (jdk1.9)

This link helped me a lot: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-annotations-resource-inject-autowire